# How to make camera shake when player collides with an obstacle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't get how to make the camera shake when my player collides with the obstacle.

Comment: This question is too broad. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve].  Theres a lot of things on how to move objects in unity, so please be specific as to what your problem with moving the camera is

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a lot of different ways to do it, depending on what you trying to do, 
and what you already did...

Like, I can think you just started learning Unity and suggest you to use OnTrigger methods to detect collision with your player, then implement a method to apply a noise to your camera position.. But, is your cam a ThirdPerson one? FirstPerson? Fixed? 2D topdown? 2D platform? 2,5D?

Do you get it? Is important to follow the guide to Ask a Question... Try to answer these questions, saying what you already did, what you already tried and I'm sure you'll find help.